# Do I require setting the full path to files in php.ini?

Tags: php, php.ini

I have "merged" php with apache bin directory, however for years I have been hardcoding the path to files as follows :

```
curl.cainfo = d:/server/bin/cacert.pem
```

-

```
browscap = d:/server/bin/browscap.ini
```

-

```
session.save_path = "N;MODE;d:/server/www/sessions"
```

Barring these 3 settings, this setup is completely portable.  Is there anyway to write those paths so they are more dynamic ?  PHP is installed into `d:/server/bin` .

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error, the full path is required, so the answer to this boolean question is as follows:

**YES**

In the current version of PHP, a full path using forward slash `/` as the path delimiter on both Windows and Linux, is required for most PHP.INI settings where a path to a file, or location for storing data needs to be set.

Comment: An error occurred during login.
An error occurred during login.
Use this command to download for free anywhere else:
Relative path

But we have to transfer that file to the specified root and path with another code, and it cannot be kept inside the package and given relative addressing. So this is not a good way.